# Update a table (that has relationships) using another table in SSIS

Tags: mysql, t-sql, ssis, etl

I want to be able to update a specific column of a table using data from another table. Here's what the two tables look like, the DB type and SSIS components used to get the tables data (btw, both ID and Code are unique).

Table1(ID, Code, Description)         [T-SQL DB accessed using ADO NET Source component]

Table2(..., Code, Description,...)    [MySQL DB accessed using ODBC Source component]

I want to update the column Table1.Description using the Table2.Description by matching them with the right Code first (because Table1.Code is the same as Table2.Code).

What i tried:

- Doing a Merge Join transformation using the Code column but I couldn't figure out how to reinsert the table because since Table1 has relationships i can't simply drop the table and replace it with the new one
- Using a Lookup transformation but since both tables are not the same type it didn't allow me to create the lookup table's connection manager (which would be for in my case MySQL)

I'm still new to SSIS but any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not simple `UPDATE t1 SET t1.Desc=t2.Desc FROM t2 WHERE t1.Code=t2.Code`? If there is some problems in direct `t2` usage then do `INSERT INTO temp_t2 SELECT Code, Desc FROM t2` into local temptable.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry since i'm still new to SSIS, but how would i execute an SQL statement inside an SSIS package ? since both tables are in different DB sources i'd have no choice but to do it through SSIS directly i think =o

Comment: Forget about SSIS, it is client to SQL Server. Create linked server to MySQL on SQL Server and use it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Akina That's amazing i never heard of linked servers, thanks for the link i will do some research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on @Akina's comments. Although using a linked server would've definitely fit, my requirement is to make an SSIS package to take care of migrating some old data.

[image: Control Flow]

The first and last are SQL tasks, while the `Migrate ICDDx` is the DFT that transfers the data to a staging table created during the first SQL task.

Here's the SQL commands that gets executed during `Create Staging Table` :

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [tempdb].[##stagedICDDx];
CREATE TABLE ##stagedICDDx (
       ID INT NOT NULL,
       Code VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
       Description NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
       ........
);
```

and here's the sql command (based on @Akina's comment) for transferring from staged to final (inside `Transfer Staged`):

```sql
UPDATE [MyDB].[dbo].[ICDDx]
   SET [ICDDx].[Description] = [##stagedICDDx].[Description]
   FROM [dbo].[##stagedICDDx]
   WHERE [ICDDx].[Code]=[##stagedICDDx].[Code]
GO
```

Here's the DFT used (both TSQL and MySQL sources return sorted output using `ORDER BY Code`, so i didnt have to insert `Sort` components before the `Merge Join`) :

[image: DFT]

Note: Btw, you have to setup the connection manager to retain/reuse the same connection so that the temporary table doesn't get deleted before we transfer data to it. If all goes well, then after the `Transfer Staged` SQL Task, the connection would be closed and the global temporary table would be deleted.